# EXC_ARITHMETIC Error in Xcode

Tags: iphone

```
if (([gameplay1.text intValue] % [gameplay3.text intValue]) == 0)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Probably this: http://i.imgur.com/RPGsd.jpg

Answer (score 7):

You have provided almost no information, but it seems to me that

```
[gameplay3.text intValue]
```

returns 0. You can't divide by zero, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can cause this, the most likely of which being that you are trying to divide by 0. What is the value of `[gameplay3.text intValue]` when this occurs?

Answer (score 1):

it because you can't divide by zero

you can add some code like

```
if(![gameplay3.text intValue]){
    gameplay3.text = "1";
}
```

before your if judgement

it should be work and not affect your results :)